# How to prevent a beamer block from overlapping with a pspicture?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

Here is what I have tried but with no success.

```
\documentclass[10pt,compress,mathserif,smaller,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm} % pour les maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %%
\usepackage{amssymb} %%
\usepackage{mathrsfs} %%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Table des matières}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Architecture du syst\`eme}
\subsection{Deux types d'architectures}
\frame{
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{L'architecture centralis\'ee}
                Le principe d'une \alert{architecture centralis\'ee} repose sur un serveur auquel se connecte tous les clients.
            \end{block}
            \input{client-server.tex}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{L'architecture d\'ecentralis\'ee}
                Dans une \alert{architecture d\'ecentralis\'ee} chaque n\oe ud du r\'eseau est \`a la fois client et \`a la fois serveur.
            \end{block}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

The image overlaps with the first block and the second block is a bit below the first. What I wanted to do was to have two definitions with a schema centered below each definition. But I could not manage to do it.

I would be very glad if someone can explain me how to do it.
[Here is the code in the file client-server.tex](http://pastebin.com/rRgneRnq)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might not be a good solution, but it'll probably work: wrap the `\input` in a `minipage`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a minipage??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated code from Incscape is absolutely a mess. If you'd done it "by hand" it would be more or less only 20 lines of code ...

Do not use minipages in the `block` envirenment it is not needed here. And change the coordinates in the file `client-server.tex` from

```
\begin{pspicture}(524.40942383,372.04724121)
```

to

```
\begin{pspicture}(524.40942383,700)%372.04724121)
```

Then you'll get the correct output:

```
\documentclass[10pt,compress,mathserif,smaller,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm} % pour les maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %%
\usepackage{amssymb} %%
\usepackage{mathrsfs} %%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Table des matières}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Architecture du syst\`eme}
\subsection{Deux types d'architectures}
\frame{
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{L'architecture centralis\'ee}
                Le principe d'une \alert{architecture centralis\'ee} repose sur un serveur auquel se connecte tous les clients.

            \input{client-server.tex}
            \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{L'architecture d\'ecentralis\'ee}
                Dans une \alert{architecture d\'ecentralis\'ee} chaque n\oe ud du r\'eseau est \`a la fois client et \`a la fois serveur.
            \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had done my images with Inkscape just because I needed the server image and the user image. Just a question why changing 372 to 700 corrected the rendering.

Comment: It is an incorrect value from inkscape. `pspicture` needs the correct width and height of the box.